# Type a function getWord () that takes a string and returns a pointer to the beginning of the word

Tags: c, string, pointers

I need to type a function getWord () that takes a string and an integer as argument. The function should return a pointer to the beginning of the word to which it refers. If word is 0, a pointer to the first word in the string will be returned, if word is 1, a pointer to the second word will be returned, etc. If word is greater or equal to the number of words in the string, NULL must be returned.

Example run:

```
ptr = getWord ("hello you", 1); / * "you" returns * / 

ptr2 = getWord ("a string", 0); / * "a" returns * / 

ptr3 = getWord ("one word", 2); / * NULL returns * /

    void getWord(char string[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(string[i]))
            printf("%c", string[i]);

        if (string[i] == ' ')
            break;
    }


}
```

Comment: You might be interested in the [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function?

Comment: What, exactly, is the question?  If you're asking us to write a function for you, to your spec, then, no.  We don't do that.

Comment: The function I have, what it does is printing out the first word of the input. I want help with using a pointer to choose what word I want to print out.

Comment: If `i` was the index of the first letter of the word, and not the space in front of it, you could just return `string + i`, since the compiler knows how large a `char` is, and can implement the addition operation. However, the way you've worked it out, you'll probably need to do a bit of math on the value of `i`. The problem is a little more difficult that it looks, particular if the line can contain variable numbers of spaces, and perhaps other types of whitespace as well. I think that even if you use `strtok()`, you'll still have to do a bit of arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

We beginners should help each other.:)

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * getWord(const char *s, size_t n)
{
    while ( ( s += strspn(s, " \t") ) != '\0' && n-- )
    {
        s += strcspn(s, " \t");
    }

    return *s ? (char *)s : (char *)0;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *s = "Hi Adrian. How are you?";
    size_t n = 0;

    for (char *p; (p = getWord(s, n)) != NULL; ++n)
    {
        printf("%zu: %s\n", n, p);
    }

    printf("\nThere are %zu words in the string\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the demonstrative program is

```
0: Hi Adrian. How are you?
1: Adrian. How are you?
2: How are you?
3: are you?
4: you?

There are 5 words in the string
```

If you want to get the output like this

```
0: Hi
1: Adrian.
2: How
3: are
4: you?

There are 5 words in the string
```

then just rewrite the loop in main the following way

```
for (char *p; (p = getWord(s, n)) != NULL; ++n)
{
    size_t len = strcspn(p, " \t");
    printf("%zu: %*.*s\n", n, ( int )len, ( int )len, p);
}
```

Comment: What the program you wrote does is counting how many words the *s contains, and that's very cool! But what I want is for the user to write an input and then from the input choose what word to write in the ouptut.

For example:

"Type in sentence: Hi how are you?"
"What word do you want to output: 2"
"are"

Comment: @Adrian You wrote in the question: "The function should return a pointer to the beginning of the word to which it refers" And the shown function returns pointer to the specified word. You can use this pointer to output the word. The program just demonstrates that the function works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do

```
char* get_word (char *string,int req_num)
{
int i;
int ns;//number of spaces
int *sp;
ns=0;
for(i=0;string[i]!='\0';i++)
{
//check for a spaces and increment ns
if (string[i]==' ')
{
++ns;
sp=(int*)realloc(sp,ns*sizeof(int));
sp[ns-1]=(int)&string[i+1];
}
//check what place you have to return
if(req_num>=ns)
return NULL;
else
return (char*)sp[req_num];
}
}
```

This code is very un-optimized and you can comeup with ways to restructure the code to optimize it to run it faster.

Answer (score 0):

This getWord() returns the (n+1)th word of input string:

```
char * getWord(char * string, int n)
{
        char str[1024] = {'\0'};
        char * delim = " \t";
        char * pch = NULL;
        char * result = NULL;
        int i = 0;

        if (string == NULL)
                return NULL;

        strcpy (str, string);
        pch = strtok (str, delim);
        while (pch != NULL)
        {
                if (i == n)
                        break;
                pch = strtok (NULL, delim);
                i++;
        }

        if (pch != NULL)
        {
                result = (char *)malloc(strlen(pch) + 1);
                if (result == NULL)
                        printf ("Failed to allocate memory\n");
                else
                        strcpy (result, pch);
        }
        return result;
}
```

If this function returns the result as not NULL, make sure to free the memory allocated to "result" variable in the function which is calling getWord().

The main() will look something like this -

```
int main ()
{
        char * ptr;
        ptr = getWord ("hello you", 1);
        if (ptr != NULL)
        {
                printf ("ptr = %s\n", ptr);
                free(ptr);
        }
        else
                printf ("ptr is NULL");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I barely understand the function, and how would main look?

Comment: @Adrain to understand the function getWord() you first need to understand the strtok(). I would suggest you read about strtok() thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple idea.
First try to implement a `next` function like this:

```
char* next( const char* str )
{
    const char delimiter = ' ';

    // skip all characters up to the first ' '
    while( *str != delimiter && *str != '\0' ) ++str;

    // may the first characters is ' ', so skip it as well
    while( *str == delimiter ) ++str;

    return str;
}
```

okay, let's test:

```
int main( )
{
    const char* first = next( "one two three four five" );
    puts( first );

    first = next( first );
    puts( first );

    first = next( first );
    puts( first );

    first = next( first );
    puts( first );
}
```

its output:

```
LSP ❱ ./a.out 
two three four five
three four five
four five
five
LSP ❱
```

Now we need to tell the `next` function that not only goes to the next word but also count how many, thus is becomes:

```
char* next( const char* str, int index )
{
    const char delimiter = ' ';

   // take care of index for us
    while( index-- ){

        while( *str != delimiter && *str != '\0' ) ++str;
        while( *str == delimiter ) ++str;

    }

    if( *str == '\0' ) return NULL;

    return str;
}
```

let's test:

```
int main( )
{
    puts( next( "one two three four five", 0 ) );
    puts( next( "one two three four five", 1 ) );
    puts( next( "one two three four five", 2 ) );
    puts( next( "one two three four five", 3 ) );
    puts( next( "one two three four five", 4 ) );

    if( next( "one two three four five", 5 ) == NULL )
        puts( "NULL was returned" );
}
```

and:

```
LSP ❱ ./a.out 
one two three four five
two three four five
three four five
four five
five
NULL was returned
LSP ❱
```

---

### feature:

```
int main( )
{
    // 1. skip white space 
    puts( next( "one      two     three      four        five", 3 ) );
    // returns: 'four        five'

    puts( "---------------" );

    // 2. easy iteration over a string 
    const char* first = "one two three four five";
    while( ( first = next2( first ) ) != NULL )
    {
        puts( first );
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
LSP ❱ ./a.out 
four        five
---------------
two three four five
three four five
four five
five
LSP ❱
```

---

For returning just a word based on an index, you can use `strdup` see `man 3 strdup` and `strchr`, see `man 3 strchr`. Thus inside the `next function` you should add (after while loop):

```
char* next( char* str, int index )
{
    const char delimiter = ' ';

    while( index-- ){

        while( *str != delimiter && *str != '\0' ) ++str;
        while( *str == delimiter ) ++str;
        if( *str == '\0' ) return NULL;

    }

    // duplicate the current string
    char* result = strdup( str );

    // find the first whitespace and make it as NUL
    result [strchr( result, ' ' ) - result ] = '\0';

    if( *result == '\0' ) return NULL;

    return result;
}
```

and inside the main:

```
int main( )
{
    char* r = next( "one      two     three      four        five", 3 );
    if( r != NULL )
    {
        puts( r );
        free( r );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "there is no word at index 3" );
    }

    char* s = next( "one      two     three      four        five", 8 );
    if( s != NULL )
    {
        puts( s );
        free( s );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "there is no word at index 8" );
    }
}
```

test:

```
LSP ❱ gcc -fsanitize=address temp.c
LSP ❱ ./a.out 
four
there is no word at index 8
LSP ❱
```

---

**NOTE** for `next2` just add:

```
if( *str == '\0' ) return NULL;
```

to the first `next` and names it `next2`
Also you should check the return value of `strdup` it may be `NULL`

Comment: Where it says "puts( next( "one two three four five", 0 ) );", it is only supposed to write out "one", how would I make that possible?

Comment: @Adrian. easy if you have access to `strchr` and `strdup`. Do you have?

Comment: @Adrian. In fact duplicate the `str` in inside the **next** then find the next whitespace and with `strchr` and that is it. `strchr` return a pointer before the white space. for example: `result [strchr( result, ' ' ) - result ] = '\0';` **NOTE** that you have to `free` the duplicated string